# Problemas al cargar pagina de suma en Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

tengo el codigo tal cual esta explicado en el video y al ejecutar la suma me da este fallo.

`index.html:26 Uncaught ReferenceError: parametros is not defined at sumar (index.html:26:30) at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (index.html:18:21) at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2:43336) at y.handle (jquery.min.js:2:41320)`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora muestro el codigo introducido

```
``<body>
        <center><h1>Ejemplo AJAX</h1></center>
        <input type="text" id="valor1">
        <input type="text" id="valor2">
        <input type="submit" value="Sumar" id="ejecutar">

        <h3 id="resultado"></h3>
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                $('#ejecutar').click(function(){
                    sumar($('#valor1').val(),$('#valor2').val());
                });
                function sumar(val1,val2){
                    var paramteros = {
                        "val1":val1,
                        "val2":val2
                    }
                    $.ajax({
                        data:parametros,
                        url:"suma.php",
                        type:"post",
                        beforeSend:function(){
                            console.log("Se esta procesando tu petición");
                        }
                    })
                    .done(function(data){
                        $('#resultado').text(data);
                    });
                }
            });
        </script>``
```

Este es el codigo donde me da el fallo es al nombrar la variable parametros que anteriormente la creo desde cero, además de otros métodos y funciones

Comment: paramteros != parametros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

has tenido simplemente un error ortográfico y el nombre de tu variable es diferente cuando la creas y cuando la usas después. Esta sería tu función:

```
function sumar(val1,val2){
                var parametros= {
                    "val1":val1,
                    "val2":val2
                }
                $.ajax({
                    data:parametros,
                    url:"suma.php",
                    type:"post",
                    beforeSend:function(){
                        console.log("Se esta procesando tu petición");
                    }
                })
                .done(function(data){
                    $('#resultado').text(data);
                });
            }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias a los dos por la ayuda